# Как можно оптимизировать данный запрос?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть большая таблица с автомобильными проездами. Периодически нужно получать запрос с датой последнего проезда. Условия указываются по полю metadata с данными типа jsonb и event_provider_uuid с данными типа uuid.

```
SELECT event_datetime FROM passages
WHERE event_provider_uuid = 'uuid провайдера'
AND metadata->>'camera_id' = '1'
ORDER BY event_datetime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Может попробовать с подзапросами?

Сначала запрос очень ускорился, когда заменил LIMIT 1 на FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY, но скорее всего дело в том, что запрос обработал буфер и выдавал его уже быстрее.

LIMIT и FETCH FIRST x ROW ONLY - планировщик обрабатывает одинаково.

Так же postgres прежде быстрее работал, когда выставлялся LIMIT 1000, а не '1'. Почему так?

Comment: Является ли `(event_provider_uuid, event_datetime)` уникальным в структуре таблицы? Если да - получить `MAX(event_datetime)` для нужного `event_provider_uuid` в подзапросе и по этому значению взять запись. Иначе не вижу путей к оптимизации.

Comment: Нет, в таблице эти значения могут повторяться. Но MAX(event_datetime) обрабатывается значительно дольше, чем если выполнить сортировку со дате и взять одно значение.

Comment: *MAX(event_datetime) обрабатывается значительно дольше, чем если выполнить сортировку со дате и взять одно значение.* При наличии соответствующего индекса? серьёзно?

Comment: Я тоже сталкиваюсь с таким поведением при использовании общих агрегатных функций, чаще всего без них быстрее. Кране интересный ресурс https://explain.tensor.ru/plan. Здесь вы можете представить планы выполнения ваших запросов, то даст больше информации тем кого вы просите о помощи. Так же возможна индексация GIN для поле JSONB https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/13/datatype-json#JSON-INDEXING.